# jquery Remove all occurence of element

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<div id="preview_invoice_container">
<table class="page_container">
    <tr>
        <td width="30%" id="position_0" class="box_container">
            <div class="box_logo"></div>
        </td>
        <td width="30%" id="position_1">
            <div class="box_logo"></div>
        </td>
        <td width="30%" id="position_2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I want to remove all occurences of the class="box_logo" **only** inside the div="preview_invoice_container"

I've tried the following : `$('#preview_invoice_container').find('.box_logo').removeClass("box_logo");`

But its not working.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's well worth taking an hour or two to read through the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It really only takes about that long, and it'll save you no end of time in the long run. Probably gives you back those two hours within a week, tops. :-)

Comment: well your code works as expected - http://jsfiddle.net/jSFFK/ : as you asked, it removes all the occurencies of the class, it doesn't remove the element itself

Comment: Your problem consist of two parts: (1) Finding the right elements (what you already have actually). For that you have to get your selector right. Have a look at the [jQuery selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) (2) Remove those elements. That is of  course also in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) and was asked [quite often on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+remove+element).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.removeClass()` actually removes the specified class from all matched elements, it doesn't remove the elements themselves.  I think what you want is:

```
$('#preview_invoice_container').find('.box_logo').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks...still trying to figure out jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Remove all occurrences of elements with the class `.box_logo` from within the specified ID:

```
$('#preview_invoice_container .box_logo').remove();
```

Comment: +1 for not stringing `children()` or `find()`. Not sure why people do that. It's completely unnecessary.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I made a quick test which shows a substantial performance difference between the two: http://jsperf.com/fvdq - I'm still getting used to jsperf, so I may have made an error in test setup/teardown/etc, but if not "completely unnecessary" seems off.  I vaguely recall something about how the selector scheme works (right to left) that makes the outcome I got somewhat sensible.

Comment: @Carl: Yes, selectors are evaluated from right to left but as long as it is a valid CSS3 selector, jQuery (or Sizzle) will use `querySelectorAll` in modern browsers (hopefully) and that will be way faster than anything else.

Comment: @FelixKling suuuuuure, but: all the browsers that have hit that test are providing consistent results.

Comment: @Carl: Right... interesting. Maybe `$('#abc').find('.xyz')` is optimized to `document.getElementById('abc').getElementsByClassName('xyz')` which might be even faster... but that is just speculation...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.box_logo', '#preview_invoice_container')​​​​​.remove();
```